# SignalExpression in Activiti 6.0 Intermediate Catching event

Tags: java, activiti

I am trying to create a process with the Intermediate Catching event with conditional expression. I can see that `SignalEventDefinition` has a property called `signalExpression`. But somehow I am not able to use it.

Here is the code from BaseBpmnXMLConverter.

```
protected void writeSignalDefinition(Event parentEvent, SignalEventDefinition signalDefinition, XMLStreamWriter xtw) throws Exception {
    xtw.writeStartElement(ELEMENT_EVENT_SIGNALDEFINITION);
    writeDefaultAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_SIGNAL_REF, signalDefinition.getSignalRef(), xtw);
    if (parentEvent instanceof ThrowEvent && signalDefinition.isAsync()) {
      BpmnXMLUtil.writeQualifiedAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVITY_ASYNCHRONOUS, "true", xtw);
    }
    boolean didWriteExtensionStartElement = BpmnXMLUtil.writeExtensionElements(signalDefinition, false, xtw);
    if (didWriteExtensionStartElement) {
      xtw.writeEndElement();
    }
    xtw.writeEndElement();
  }
```

I don't see how can we create signalExpression inside `signalEventDefinition`.

I can even see the signalExpression is considered in `IntermediateCatchSignalEventActivityBehavior` as well as in `EventValidator`. So It looks like I don't know how to use signalExpression inside catching event. Can someone please help me find the right way.

I am using Activiti 6.0 and my own custom UI to create BPMN model which in turn calls activiti-bpmn-converter to generate the process definition XML.

Comment: The attribute signalExpression is apparently part of extension elements and is not part of BPMN 2.0 specification. If you export your process definition XML file you will notice it with activiti prefix e. g. "activiti:signalExpression". Perhaps this article may help you https://forum.flowable.org/t/expressions-in-signal-event-definition/4060.

Comment: Thanks @RokProdan , based on this I was able to extend CatchEventXMLConverter and model my workflow with this extension field. Had to add my implementation to BpmnXMLConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to get it working

```
 BpmnXMLConverter.addConverter(new CatchEventXMLConverter() {
      @Override
      protected void writeSignalDefinition(Event parentEvent,
          SignalEventDefinition signalDefinition, XMLStreamWriter xtw) throws Exception {
        xtw.writeStartElement(ELEMENT_EVENT_SIGNALDEFINITION);
        writeDefaultAttribute("activiti:"+ATTRIBUTE_SIGNAL_EXPRESSION, signalDefinition.getSignalExpression(), xtw);
        if (parentEvent instanceof ThrowEvent && signalDefinition.isAsync()) {
          BpmnXMLUtil.writeQualifiedAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVITY_ASYNCHRONOUS, "true", xtw);
        }
        boolean didWriteExtensionStartElement =
            BpmnXMLUtil.writeExtensionElements(signalDefinition, false, xtw);
        if (didWriteExtensionStartElement) {
          xtw.writeEndElement();
        }
        xtw.writeEndElement();
      }
    });
((ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl) activitiRule.getProcessEngine()
    .getProcessEngineConfiguration())
        .setActivityBehaviorFactory(new DefaultActivityBehaviorFactory() {
          @Override
          public IntermediateCatchSignalEventActivityBehavior createIntermediateCatchSignalEventActivityBehavior(
              IntermediateCatchEvent intermediateCatchEvent,
              SignalEventDefinition signalEventDefinition, Signal signal) {


            return new IntermediateCatchSignalEventActivityBehavior(signalEventDefinition,
                signal) {
              /**
                   * 
                   */
              private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

              @Override
              public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
                CommandContext commandContext = Context.getCommandContext();
                ExecutionEntity executionEntity = (ExecutionEntity) execution;

                String signalName = null;

                Expression signalExpression =
                    commandContext.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getExpressionManager()
                        .createExpression(signalEventDefinition.getSignalExpression());
                signalName = signalExpression.getValue(execution).toString();


                commandContext.getEventSubscriptionEntityManager().insertSignalEvent(signalName,
                    signal, executionEntity);
              }

            };
          }

        });
```